# How to debug selenium webdriver through eclipse using maven and junit

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven, selenium-webdriver

I have a bunch of selenium webdriver tests in eclipse. How can I run them in debug mode through eclipse so I can properly debug them instead of just outputting stuff to the log?

When I run the tests I use the following command line:

```
mvn -Dtest=*testName* test -Dconf=MyPropertis.properties
```

but I don't know how to do this through eclipse.

Comment: Do you want to debug the Selenium code or the server code?

Comment: I want to debug my selenium tests.

Comment: I think it should be possible to simply launch the unit test in debug mode using Eclipse. Concerning the system property, you are giving, you can also set it using the Eclipse properties of the launcher. Have you tried this?

Comment: I'm new to eclipse and not heard of this. Do you have an example of using this?

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, I would suggest to run the JUnit test in Eclipse in debug mode (1) and adapt the configuration to add the needed system property (2).

[image]

[image]